# Create language mirror sites in Umbraco

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a Umbraco site that supports 3 languages. And i want to add content to all 3 sites at the same time, I dont want to add the same content on all 3 sites 3 times. If i add content on the English site I also want it to be added on the Swedish and Danish site. So I only have to translate all text on the sites instead of the whole structure. Is this possible to accomplish? Or do i have to take the long process and do it all 3 times every time i want to add 1 small thing?

I dont want to create templates, the sites must be changed dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently only really two options for doing multi-language sites in Umbraco.

**Option 1:** you create the sites separately for each language and manage accordingly. This is what you're describing above with having to add it three times. You could make your life easier by writing an event handler that listens for changes (e.g. add, move, delete) on the primary language site and replicates those changes on the other sites. You'd still have to enter the actual page content on three sites though.

**Option 2:** this might be trickier for you, as it sounds like the site is already built, but you can use package called [Vorto](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/vorto/) that allows you to have a single site structure and just translate the text for each property on the pages. The only caveat with this method is that all of the sites must have EXACTLY the same structure.

You can also combine the two methods for the best of best worlds if you want. It's also worth noting that the next major version of Umbraco (v8) will have much better support for multi language setups.

Comment: Thanks ill take a look at Vorto and see if i can use it.